# RShiny FlexDashboard not Rendering

Tags: r, shinydashboard, flexdashboard

Attemping to run an example RShiny Flexdashboard and when executing the `rmarkdown::run` command on the .Rmd file with the source code found here:

http://rmarkdown.rstudio.com/flexdashboard/shiny.html#getting_started

The rendered dashboard appears as such:

[image: Incorrect Flexdashboard Example]

which is incorrect.  None of the text or code should be rendering on the page. Essentially, I copied & pasted the source code found on that tutorial page into an test.Rmd file, and then executed `rmarkdown::run("test.Rmd")`.  Is there more to a flexdashboard than doing what I've described?

Thanks for the time! I really appreciate the help!

Comment: The correct rendered version of that shiny dashboard can be found at that tutorial link as well.   Again, thanks for the help!

Comment: Your YAML frontmatter (which tells RMarkdown that it's a FlexDashboard) is apparently incorrectly formatted, as you can see from the fact that it's showing up on the rendered page. Check your dashes and indentation.

Comment: Thanks for the tip - I'd assumed something was incorrect with the file.  I've toyed with changing various aspect of the file but no luck so far.  Need to find an example of a appropriately formatted file.

Comment: The code below the example is correct, and should run if copied into an Rmd and everything is installed.

Comment: Might be worth checking if you have the shinydashboard package loaded... it can conflict with flexdashboard and cause it not to render

Comment: I just ran a flexdashboard for the first time after many months, and had the same problem you did. Which was very surprising because I have done this thousands of times. I made sure the first three YAML were title: runtime: output: and deleted extraneous YAML in between those three, and then it worked.

Answer (score -1):

There are 2 things that come to my mind-

1) Can you send a screenshot of your Rstudio window. I am guessing that your R-code is not withing a chunk, which maybe causing it to display as code

2) Can you use the run document button on the top of the Rstudio window instead of `rmarkdown::run`

Please let me know